# Selecting a row where range lies between two columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model `Charge`.  The model has 3 properties, 
        `'max'`,
        `'min'`,
        `'charge'`,

The data is as below,

row 1 => `min: 0 max: 100 charge: 0`,

row 2 => `min: 101 max: 200 charge: 10`,

row 3 => `min: 201 max: 300 charge: 30`

I want an eloquent query that when a certain amount is passed and it lies between a certain range ie (min and max) to return the charge of that row.

Unfortunately, I can not think of a way.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$amount = 105; //suppose
$query->where('min', '<=', $amount)
      ->where('max', '>=', $amount)
      ->get('charge');
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

Comment: A user passes amount say 150, you check where that lies between the min and max range.... From the above, that's row two hence return 10 which is the charge

Comment: @Saurabh You have to swap your conditions (`min >=` becomes `<=` and the same for max)

Comment: @Xatenev Oh sorry, my bad.

Comment: @Saurabh though should be `->value('charge');` instead of get();

Comment: If it will only return one value then you can even use `->first(['charge']);` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Charge::where('min', '<=', $value)
      ->where('max','>=',$value)
      ->get('charge');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel predefined function for that:-

```
$users = DB::table('table_name')->whereBetween('column_name', [1, 100])->get();
```

Ref. Link: - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: This is not what OP asked for.